# How Can I Separate Cell Data to Specific Column Automatically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

I want to separate Excel Cell Value With Specific Column. 
Please, Check the screenshot.

[image: Current Excel File]

I want to Separate all **Date of Birth** in one column, all age cell in **Age** Column. How Can I do it?
[image: This is What I want]

Automatically cell will move the specific column.

Comment: please post your desired output also.

Comment: What about the profession? You just need DOB, age and Born/birthplace?

Comment: Sort the columns for each row?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and where you have run into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in cell F3

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(F$2="","",IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$D$6001,ROW($A1),MATCH(F$2&"*",$B3:$D3,0)),"")),IF(F$1="","",IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$D$6001,ROW($A1),MATCH(F$1&"*",$B3:$D3,0)),"")))
```

Put your partial search values in range `F1:H2`(1st row is used in case you have multiple search words for same column. Your data should start from cell `A3`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming strings `Date of Birth :-`, `Age :-`, `Born :-`, `Birthplace :-`, etc. are consistent through out the sheet.

In `Cell F1` enter following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:D1,1,MATCH("Date of Birth :-",INDEX(LEFT(B1:D1,16),0),0)),"")
```

In `Cell G1` enter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:D1,1,MATCH("Age :-",INDEX(LEFT(B1:D1,6),0),0)),"")
```

And in `Cell H1` enter following **array formula**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B1:D1,1,MATCH(1,("Born :-"=LEFT(Sheet1!B1:D1,7))+("Birthplace :-"=LEFT(Sheet1!B1:D1,13)),0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down all formula as required. Change `B1:D1` to your column range. See image for reference.

***Note :*** Array formula needs to be committed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

---

If you want result in different sheet then, assuming your data is in `Sheet1` and you want output in `Sheet2`.

Enter following formula in `Cell A1` of `Sheet2`

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Then enter following formula in `Cell B2` of `Sheet2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B1:D1,1,MATCH("Date of Birth :-",INDEX(LEFT(Sheet1!B1:D1,16),0),0)),"")
```

Enter following formula in `Cell C2` of `Sheet2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B1:D1,1,MATCH("Age :-",INDEX(LEFT(Sheet1!B1:D1,6),0),0)),"")
```

Finally in `Cell D2` enter following **array formula**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B1:D1,1,MATCH(1,("Born :-"=LEFT(Sheet1!B1:D1,7))+("Birthplace :-"=LEFT(Sheet1!B1:D1,13)),0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy down all formula as required. Change `B1:D1` to your column range. See image for reference.

[image]

---